# Как получить ключи только родительских элементов массива json рhp

Tags: php, массивы, json

Необходимо с помощью php вывести все (1 2 4 9) значения только родительских ключей

```
"1": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Тюриков Т.",
    "city": "Нижний Новгород",
    "car": "Audi R8"
},

"2": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Волик А.",
    "city": "Санкт-Петербург",
    "car": "Subaru Impreza"
},

"4": {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Арутюнян А.",
    "city": "Армавир",
    "car": "Audi RS7 Seven Force Stage 3"
},

"9": {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Голына А.",
    "city": "пос.Власиха",
    "car": "Audi TT RS"
},
```

Преобразование json в массив и декодирование

```
<?php
    $dataCars = file_get_contents("data_cars.json");
    $array = json_decode($dataCars, true);
?>
```

Comment: `array_keys` уже изобрели. Как и гугл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arrayKeys = array_keys(json_decode($dataCars, true));
```

Ссылка на док: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-keys.php

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, таким образом выводил, однако только сейчас понял что массив выводится только через var_dump();